# javax.naming.InvalidNameException using Oracle BPM and weblogic when accessing directory

Tags: oracle, weblogic

We are getting this exception when we start our cluster (2 managed servers, 1 admin), we have deployed only the ears corresponding to the OBPM 10.3.1 SP1 in a weblogic 10.3. When the server  cluster starts, one of the managed servers (the first to start) get overloaded and ran out of connections to the directory DB because of this repeatedly error. It looks like the engine is trying to get the info from the LDAP server but I don't know why it is building a wrong query.

```
fuego.directory.DirectoryRuntimeException: Exception [javax.naming.InvalidNameException: CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo
DEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-031001BA, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349, best match of:
        'CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo
DEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp,dc=televisa,dc=com,dc=mx'
^@]; remaining name 'CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo
DEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp'].
        at fuego.directory.DirectoryRuntimeException.wrapException(DirectoryRuntimeException.java:85)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.JNDIQueryExecutor.selectById(JNDIQueryExecutor.java:163)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.JNDIQueryExecutor.selectById(JNDIQueryExecutor.java:110)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.Repository.selectById(Repository.java:38)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.msad.MSADGroupValueProvider.getAssignedParticipantsInternal(MSADGroupValueProvider.java:124)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.msad.MSADGroupValueProvider.getAssignedParticipants(MSADGroupValueProvider.java:70)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.Group$7.getValue(Group.java:149)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.Group$7.getValue(Group.java:152)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.LDAPResult.getValue(LDAPResult.java:76)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.setInfo(LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.java:352)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.build(LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.java:121)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.build(LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.java:114)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.fetchGroup(LDAPOrganizationGroupAccessor.java:94)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.HybridGroupAccessor.fetchGroup(HybridGroupAccessor.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at fuego.directory.provider.DirectorySessionImpl$AccessorProxy.invoke(DirectorySessionImpl.java:756)
        at $Proxy66.fetchGroup(Unknown Source)
        at fuego.directory.DirOrganizationalGroup.fetch(DirOrganizationalGroup.java:275)
        at fuego.metadata.GroupManager.loadGroup(GroupManager.java:225)
        at fuego.metadata.GroupManager.find(GroupManager.java:57)
        at fuego.metadata.ParticipantManager.addNestedGroups(ParticipantManager.java:621)
        at fuego.metadata.ParticipantManager.buildCompleteRoleAssignments(ParticipantManager.java:527)
        at fuego.metadata.Participant$RoleTransitiveClousure.build(Participant.java:760)
        at fuego.metadata.Participant$RoleTransitiveClousure.access$100(Participant.java:692)
        at fuego.metadata.Participant.buildRoles(Participant.java:401)
        at fuego.metadata.Participant.updateMembers(Participant.java:372)
        at fuego.metadata.Participant.<init>(Participant.java:64)
        at fuego.metadata.Participant.createUncacheParticipant(Participant.java:84)
        at fuego.server.persistence.jdbc.JdbcProcessInstancePersMgr.loadItems(JdbcProcessInstancePersMgr.java:1706)
        at fuego.server.persistence.Persistence.loadInstanceItems(Persistence.java:838)
        at fuego.server.AbstractInstanceService.readInstance(AbstractInstanceService.java:791)
        at fuego.ejbengine.EJBInstanceService.getLockedROImpl(EJBInstanceService.java:218)
        at fuego.server.AbstractInstanceService.getLockedROImpl(AbstractInstanceService.java:892)
        at fuego.server.AbstractInstanceService.getLockedImpl(AbstractInstanceService.java:743)
        at fuego.server.AbstractInstanceService.getLockedImpl(AbstractInstanceService.java:730)
        at fuego.server.AbstractInstanceService.getLocked(AbstractInstanceService.java:144)
        at fuego.server.AbstractInstanceService.getLocked(AbstractInstanceService.java:162)
        at fuego.server.AbstractInstanceService.unselectAllItems(AbstractInstanceService.java:454)
        at fuego.server.execution.ToDoItemUnselect.execute(ToDoItemUnselect.java:105)
        at fuego.server.execution.DefaultEngineExecution$AtomicExecutionTA.runTransaction(DefaultEngineExecution.java:304)
        at fuego.transaction.TransactionAction.startNestedTransaction(TransactionAction.java:527)
        at fuego.transaction.TransactionAction.startTransaction(TransactionAction.java:548)
        at fuego.transaction.TransactionAction.start(TransactionAction.java:212)
        at fuego.server.execution.DefaultEngineExecution.executeImmediate(DefaultEngineExecution.java:123)
        at fuego.server.execution.DefaultEngineExecution.executeAutomaticWork(DefaultEngineExecution.java:62)
        at fuego.server.execution.EngineExecution.executeAutomaticWork(EngineExecution.java:42)
        at fuego.server.execution.ToDoItem.executeAutomaticWork(ToDoItem.java:261)
        at fuego.ejbengine.ItemExecutionBean$1.execute(ItemExecutionBean.java:223)
        at fuego.server.execution.DefaultEngineExecution$AtomicExecutionTA.runTransaction(DefaultEngineExecution.java:304)
        at fuego.transaction.TransactionAction.startBaseTransaction(TransactionAction.java:470)
        at fuego.transaction.TransactionAction.startTransaction(TransactionAction.java:551)
        at fuego.transaction.TransactionAction.start(TransactionAction.java:212)
        at fuego.server.execution.DefaultEngineExecution.executeImmediate(DefaultEngineExecution.java:123)
        at fuego.server.execution.EngineExecution.executeImmediate(EngineExecution.java:66)
        at fuego.ejbengine.ItemExecutionBean.processMessage(ItemExecutionBean.java:209)
        at fuego.ejbengine.ItemExecutionBean.onMessage(ItemExecutionBean.java:120)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:466)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:371)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:327)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4547)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4233)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3709)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:114)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5058)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo
DEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp: [LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-031001BA, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8349, best match of:
        'CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo
DEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp,dc=televisa,dc=com,dc=mx'
^@]; remaining name 'CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo
DEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2979)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2794)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1826)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1749)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:368)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:338)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:321)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:248)
        at fuego.jndi.FaultTolerantLdapContext.search(FaultTolerantLdapContext.java:612)
        at fuego.directory.hybrid.ldap.JNDIQueryExecutor.selectById(JNDIQueryExecutor.java:136)
        ... 67 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally solved the problem. It was caused by a special character inside the LDAP query.
The OBPM engine scape the string \0A as a new line, the string appears after Bernardo in the query:

```
'CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo\0ADEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp,dc=televisa,dc=com,dc=mx'
```

and when the engine parse the query, it looks like:

```
'CN=Alvarez Guerrero Bernardo
DEL:ca9ef28d-3b94-4e8f-a6bd-8c880bb3791b,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=corp,dc=televisa,dc=com,dc=mx'
```

We don't know why the query contains the "\0A" string but the OBPM was cycling executing that query in the first run after migration. We insert some code into the Oracle code to remove the string and the problem was solved. After that, we restore the original code from Oracle and the problem didn't appear again.